# Why one server is able to ping the other but not vice versa?

Tags: networking, windows-server, windows-server-2019

This often happens and it kind of solves itself after a while or after reboots. But I would like to stop relying on luck and understand why one server can ping the other but not the other way around.

Notice that neither pings were working before one of them started working

[image]

**Edit:**
Just to add more information, the server that is not able to ping the other is a AD controller server. The other one is a regular windows server 2019 without anything on it.

Comment: The server which cannot ping has the wrong DNS Server.  Unless it’s a DNS server itself, it won’t be able to resolve anything that isn’t in the hosts file, since it’s DNS Server is configured to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @ramhound except the pings were to IP addresses, so no DNS resolution is required.

Comment: @davidgo replied before I could, yes there is no DNS for those servers only IP so no DNS work is required here I think.

Comment: I tried adding to the host file anyway, the IP with the computer names, the behavior persists

Comment: I am still suspicious of the DNS server being 127.0.0.1 is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Server 2019 might block inbound pings:

- Run : Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
- On the left pane click Inbound Rules
- Click the Name column to sort the rules for easier access
- Find the two rules titled
  "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)",
  right-click each rule and choose "Enable Rule".

This should enable ping to this server.